# how does __FD_ISSET macro function work

Tags: c, linux, macros

There is a macro definition in sys/select.h which is part of GNU C Library as follows

```
#define __FD_ISSET(d, set) \
  ((__FDS_BITS (set)[__FD_ELT (d)] & __FD_MASK (d)) != 0)
```

Can someone explain how the second line actually expands and how it works?
where are __FDS_BITS/__FD_ELT/__FD_MASK defined? (are they macros by themself?)

Comment: What does, indeed. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30574656/edit) your question to add the missing part.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Debian/GNU Linux), it is defined as this:

```
# define __FDS_BITS(set) ((set)->__fds_bits)
#define __FD_ELT(d) ((d) / __NFDBITS)
#define __FD_MASK(d)    ((__fd_mask) 1 << ((d) % __NFDBITS))
```

What FD_ISSET does you can find in manual (man FD_ISSET, or man 2 select)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where did you find the definitions (in which header file)?

Comment: On my Debian amd64, it is in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h and /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/select.h

Comment: BTW, by asking how it EXPANDS and how it WORKS, I am looking for how the macro rules in C apply here; I cant understand how the chain of macros used in the 2nd line expand?

Comment: The macros work by replacing, e.g. you can replace "__FDS_BITS(set)" with "((set)->__fds_bits)".  For example "#define __FD_SET(d, set) ((void) (__FDS_BITS (set)[__FD_ELT (d)] |= __FD_MASK (d)))" can also be written as "#define FD_SET(fd, fdsetp) ((void) (((fdsetp)->__fds_bits) [((fd) / __NFDBITS)] |= __FD_MASK (fd)))" and so on with __NFDBITS, __FD_MASK, etc.